# Cancel NSThread

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

This is how i create a thread:

```
readFromWebThread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(loadThread:) object:urlStr];
```

And this is how i stop it :

```
if ([readFromWebThread isExecuting]) {
    [readFromWebThread cancel];
}
```

And this is what i excute in the thread:

```
-(void)loadThread:(NSString*)urlStr {
    while (YES) {
        //MyStuff

        [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:kSleepBetweenLoading];
    }
}
```

And the problem is that even call the cancel thread method the thread keep calling.
Any idea whats can be the mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the docs:

-cancel: "Changes the cancelled state of the receiver to indicate that it should exit."

==> you have to to implement the cancelation of the thread! and if it sleeps it never gets canceled

e.g.

```
while(YES) {
    //do a piece of work
    if([NSThread currentThread].state == canceled)
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`-cancel` merely sets a flag. You have to check the flag.

```
while (!self.isCancelled) {
    // MyStuff
}
```

Comment: Note to OP: "if it sleeps it never gets canceled. don't just sleep it"